# How to clear space on c drive on windows 7 laptop

Tags: storage

I had to download the latest iPhone software update via iTunes, as my iphone’s Wi-fi stopped working. I have installed the update on my phone, but the c drive on my laptop is now full and in the red. Can I delete the software update from my laptop; if so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) See if you can find the update file(s) under `\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It is about clearing space on the HD of a Windows PC

Comment: Well - this is on topic since they are using Apple Software Update on PC. It’s on topic for Super User as well and might get a better answer there. The “how do I delete” is really best on SU, but they may or may not know if it’s “prudent to remove it” I think this should be closed as too broad so the OP can pick - do they want to know if they can remove it or how to once they decide to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

On the Apple iTunes end - I would do anything to not remove the Apple Software Update program since it’s small and provides security updates.

Run a tool to find large files you can delete. Removing the installer or the application is really a mole hill compared to the mountain of video files, music files, other files you might have hanging around on the C:

If this is about *should* you delete that app, I say no. Either uninstall iTunes entirely and uninstall the update tool or keep both and find another way to save space or move data files to a different drive.

Comment: And how to remove the programs, just use the usual “add/remove” programs tool windows provides if you want to go that way...